# How to read 400 or 500 JSON response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a Nodejs server running that registers the users. On successful registration, it returns a status code of 200 and a JSON response. But on unsuccessful registration where the email already exists, it returns the status code of 400 and a JSON response.
Now the problem is that I'm able to read the JSON of 200 responses but I'm not able to access the JSON of 400 responses. I am using `axios` to fetch the data from the server.

**Code for the email that already exists**

```
if (emailExists) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'This email address is already being used.'
    })
}
```

**Response for a valid registration**

```
return res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    message: 'You are signed up successfully.',
})
```

**Response on successful signup**
[image]

**Behaviour when the email is already being used**
[image]

**This is how I'm sending the request**
[image]

Comment: What does your client code look like? How are you sending the request and how are you handling any failures?

Comment: I updated the post and added the request code in the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `axios()`, to handle a 400 error, you need to use a `.catch()` to catch the rejected promise and then examine the error object you get.  So, in addition to your `.then()`, use a `.catch()`:

```
axios(...).then((result) => {
   console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response.status);
    console.log(err.response.data);
});
```

Or, if you were using an `await fetch(...)`, then surround that with a `try/catch` and catch the error in the `catch` block.

In your code ALL promises that can ever reject MUST have an error handler for the rejection.  Since your console shows "uncaught (in promise) Error", that means you had no means of catching the rejected promise.

Comment: It just prints 'Request failed with status code 400', etc. and doesn't print that JSON response

Comment: @dipansh - I'd suggest you read about handling errors in `axios()` right [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors) .  You can probably see the status at `err.response.status` and your JSON data at `err.response.data` as shown in the recent edit to my answer.

Comment: Yeah! Actually, this is what I was looking for. I needed to get the response and I now I can get that with 'error.response'. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the response before they are handled by then or catch. Example below:

```
 // Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Doc reference: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors